# Eclipse keyboard navigation

Tags: eclipse, accessibility, typing

Since Catalina doesn't support 32bits version of Eclipse anymore I was forced to upgrade to a new version.
Unfortunately a lot has changed since the version I was used to code.
One of the things that I've notice is that the keyboard navigation through text is not consider some characters as word separators, like a "dot", for example.
In earlier versions I was able to navigate through text with Option+Left|Right like this:

**|console|.|log|(|matches|)|;**

But now, when I type Options+Left|Right the cursor moves like this:

**|console.log|(matches|);**

Is there any way to tell Eclipse which characters I want to consider a word separator so my cursor will stop there?

Comment: That depends on the editor. For example, the Java editor is camelCase aware in contrast to the plain text editor. In Eclipse 2021-03, for me it's like you described in the first case using the Java or the text editor. Or with other word, I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2021-03 in the Java editor. About which editor exactly are you talking?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse IDE for PHP Developers (includes Incubating components)

Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552

Thanks for replying